# Problems with using Sessions in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, session, session-variables

I am developing web application, nothing special.

There a lot of users and each user has got a lot of projects.

To store data I used the Session container.

When user was opening the project it was like (as example)

```
Session["projectId"] = current_project_id;
Session["projectName"] = current_project_name;
```

so as you see when user opening lets say 2nd project in other tab, data about 1st project just replaces with the 2nd project data.

It's really bad, yeah.

So I was interesting in how to build application in such way that different users could open their different projects in different tabs and everything was working fine, without any data loss.

I read about `TempData` and `ViewBag`, but still can't imagine how could I replace those Session variables.

What can help me? What should I use to store new data for each new tab?

Comment: What type of data are you storing in the session?  Why do you need it in the session?  Session is less what's intended with MVC, as it's meant to be a more stateless design.

Comment: @mckeejm I store some `id`s in purpose to get some data from database in controllers

Comment: an example - user choose it's project (or creating one) after it `project_id` saved in `Session["project_id"]`

Comment: I want to user could choose few projects and works with them like in parallel

Comment: so don't store those ids in the session, drop those ids in the url and get them via the controller that way. That will make them unique per tab, since the url will be different.

Answer (score 2):

You could store a List or Dictionary of projects in the Session:

```
var projects = new Dictionary<int, string>();
projects.Add(projectId, projectName);

Session["UserProjects"] = projects;
```

And later:

```
var projects = (Dictionary<int, string>)Session["UserProjects"];
```

Comment: well, there are data about few projects in `projects` variable? but how I suppose to choose just one wic I need from it? Or maybe I understand something worng?

Comment: Based on your projectId?  If you want to store more details that just the project name, you can change the dictionary to `Dictionary<int, Project>`, where Project is your model of a project.

Comment: Well, I mean how it will store different data for let say different tabs (if in these tabs were opened diferent projects, of course) and use just one container when one project has been open in few tabs and etc

Comment: Each tab has a project information.  Each project is identified by the ProjectId.  Each tab has a project, and therefore knows the ProjectId.  You ask the Session for the project details:`((Dictionary<int, Project>)Session["UserProjects"])[projectId]`

Comment: Thanks I try to rewrite stuff in this way! (+1 if it would work perfectly as I need I'll mark it as answer :) )

Comment: this is a valid solution, but I believe it's not the intended practice with MVC (using session like this)

Comment: @mckeejm well, what is the other option then?

Comment: having a based viewmodel that gets returned as part of the strongly typed view you are presenting.  This base viewmodel could hold these type of values that you intend to use across every view.  If you go with the session state , keep in mind things like needing to configure sticky session at the load balancer ( assuming your product web app is configured on in a "web farm" style ... see this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/25c78a/load-balancing-session-state-configuration/).  If you start relying heavily on session state your app may not scale as well.